# How to get Scrollbar for barchart in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, chart.js

I am using chart.js and am trying to add a scroll bar in a barchart by making sure that the gap between the bars remain the same.

```
<div class="{{chartType === 'devicesByNetwork' ? 'col-10 net' : 'col-12 mn'}}" style="height:auto; margin: 0 auto;" *ngIf="showChart">
   <canvas class="deviceDept" *ngIf="chartType === 'devicesByNetwork'"  style="margin-top:30px;"  height="250px" baseChart
           [datasets]="barChartData"
           [labels]="barChartLabels"
           [options]="barChartOptionsdevicesByNetwork"
           [legend]="barChartLegend"
           [chartType]="barChartType"
           [colors]="myColors"
           (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
           (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>

</div>
```